# jQuery replace div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am playing around with Bootstrap modal and I want to change content of div when clicking a button. Here is the code :

*html code of modal content*

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div id="login-box" class="animated fadeIn">
        Login form
        <button id="show-register">Register</button>
    </div>
    <div id="register-box" class="animated fadeIn">
        Register form
        <button id="show-login">Login</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*css styling*

```
#register-box {
    display: none;
}
```

*javascript function to hide/show div*

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  loginRegisterSwitch();
 });

function loginRegisterSwitch(){
    var registerBtn = $("#show-register");
    var loginBtn = $("#show-login");
    var registerBox = $("register-box");
    var loginBox = $("#login-box");

    registerBtn.on('click',function(){
        loginBox.hide();
        registerBox.css('display','block');
    });

    loginBtn.on('click', function(){
        registerBox.hide();
        loginBox.css('display','block');
    });
}
```

*When user clicks register button, login-form div hides and register box shows.I can't get this code working(When user click register button , register div shows but login div does not hide). I would like to know if there is a better way to achieve this for example using jQuery `html()`*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the # in the selector for the registerBox.

Change `var registerBox = $("register-box");` to `var registerBox = $("#register-box");`

Comment: I was wondering what is wrong with my logic. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: was about to answer this myself but @webbm was faster :) any way i suggest to use the `.show()` method instead of the `.css`